# What are the image datasets that pre trained weights are available in keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, tensorflow-datasets

I want to know,
what are the datasets that the pretrained weights are available in keras. Let's say keras inception v3 model refering the weights of imagenet dataset.

```
keras.applications.InceptionV3(weights='imagenet')
```

But I want to know other datasets like imagenet?

Answer (score 1):

It says in the docs: `One of None (random initialization), imagenet (pre-training on ImageNet), or the path to the weights file to be loaded. Default to imagenet.` Link to the docs: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/InceptionV3

Comment: Thanks for replying. But the question is whether it provides only weights for imagenet. not for like coco?

Comment: No. The docs state that the options are: `[None, "imagenet", path_to_weights_file]`, and that's it.

Comment: Thank you. That is the answer.